# How do you make numbers line up on the right side?

Tags: c++

It seems like setw() makes numbers line up on the left, like:

```
a    $32
b    $34.3
c    $22.93
```

But how can you do something like this:

```
a       $32
b     $34.3
c    $22.93
```

Answer (score 6):

use "std::right" like this:

```
std::cout << std::right << std::setw(10) << x << std::endl;
```

to handle multiple outputs, you can use stringstream like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

char someChar = 'a';
double cost = 0;
stringstream ss;

ss << "$" << cost;
std::cout << someChar << std::right << std::setw(10) << ss.str() << std::endl;

// This line to clear the stringstream
ss.str("");
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `setprecision()` exists in case you want to line up on the decimal.

Comment: How would you incorporate a dollar sign into the code you've written above so that it looks like the second thing I want to output in my OP?

Comment: If I try something like cout << "Cost: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(8) << right << cost << endl; this fails. Why is that?

Comment: @user3064097 you can solve "$" problem by using stringstream, I'll update the answer to support that.

Comment: @user3064097 for using "fixed with right" problem, I currently don't know why, but it works fine if you used  cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed); any place before cout << "Cost: " << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << right << cost << endl;

I'll try to know why and I'll comeback to you.